# rshinydashboard dynamic submenu items not rendering

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

ui.R:

```
library(shinydashboard)

dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title='Dynamic Submenus'),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenuOutput("menu")
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem("default", "Hello, World!"),
      tabItem("dynatab", "Dynamic tab!")
    )
  )
)
```

server.R:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$menu <- renderMenu({
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard"), tabName = "default"),
      menuItem("Root Menu", icon = icon("book"),
        menuSubItem("Add New Submenu", icon = icon("plus"), tabName = "dynatab")
      )
    )
  })
})
```

---

The page will render "Dashboard" and "Root Menu", with a "<" next to Root Menu indicating it has submenus but clicking the menu item doesn't provide a dropdown.

Anybody know why this isn't working? Allowing the user to generate submenus is something that I'd really like to be able to do with my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just so you know, Winston Chang just pushed a fix for this problem to the shinydashboard [github repo](https://github.com/rstudio/shinydashboard/issues/54).